# Authentication problems, then using Wildfly ActiveMQ from remote host

Tags: jms, wildfly

I am sorry for probably simple question.
I am using ActiveMQ on Wildfly. While working on Local machine no problems appeared. But then my client application moved to remote hosts I start getting following error:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://10.76.46.211:8080 (Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\work\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\auth\local7244391904621911627.challenge (No such file or directory)]
   DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException])] [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\work\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\auth\local7244391904621911627.challenge (No such file or directory)]
   DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]]
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:238)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:149)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:130)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at com.emc.PerfRPQA.ATestAgent.taConsumer.run(taConsumer.java:87)
        at com.emc.PerfRPQA.ATestAgent.ATestAgent.main(ATestAgent.java:71)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\work\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\auth\local7244391904621911627.challenge (No such file or directory)]
   DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Cannot perform callback to acquire realm, authentication ID or password [Caused by javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException]
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener.allMechanismsFailed(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:114)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:389)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:241)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:199)
        at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:113)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$DelegatingChannelListener.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:1092)
        at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
        at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
        at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
        at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:275)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:379)
        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:363)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.EndpointCache$EndpointWrapper.connect(EndpointCache.java:111)
        at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:197)
        ... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: RHEL1: RHEL1: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1438)
        at com.emc.PerfRPQA.ATestAgent.ATestAgent.main(ATestAgent.java:76)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: RHEL1: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:866)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1258)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1434)
        ... 1 more
```

Here is configuration of JMS

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
    <server name="default">
        <cluster password="ATest" user="ATestAgent"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
            <role name="ATestAgent" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="ATestQ" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/ATestQ"/>
        <jms-topic name="ATestT" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/ATestT"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" thread-pool-max-size="1024" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

ATestQ and ATestT are used by me.

I already double verified does used user created correctly and rest thing I found in I-net as potential problem. But nothing fixed the problem.

Any advises?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. It indeed was simple. 
My “Properties” for “context.lookup” didn’t include Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS. So according to Authentication configuration Local connection was authenticated without user name and password. But remote one required these parameters.